"Alternate page with proper canonical tag" - Same page, different URL, should I use redirect to fix the issue?
I have recently came across to an issue with "Alternate page with proper canonical tag" in Google Search Console.
I've got several pages that are been flagged here:
Here is an example:
The page that is being indexed is:
domain.com/category/sub-category/my-article-about-food
The page that comes up under "Alternate page with proper canonical tag" is:
domain.com/category/my-article-about-food
I can access both URLs, but both are the same identical single page, just accessed by a different URL. There are no duplicate pages.
I'm guessing this happened when I was changing the page structure as one instance has the 'sub-category', the other doesn't.
But what do I do in this case? Should I just setup a 301 redirect from domain.com/category/my-article-about-food to domain.com/category/sub-category/my-article-about-food ?

First I will check which of those links are actually indexed in Google. Before any 301 redirect. Then, check which link has more external backlinks and internal backlinks. This data will give you the best answer. I hope this help.

Your indexed page is: domain.com/category/sub-category/my-article-about-food
The page that comes up under "Alternate page with proper canonical tag" is: domain.com/category/my-article-about-food
So you need to redirect it like this -
domain.com/category/sub-category/my-article-about-food   --> 301 to
domain.com/category/my-article-about-food
if redirect not possible than add 2nd URL as canonical to 1st URL.

Thanks Ajit, but shouldn't I be redirecting the other way around?:  /category/my-article-about-food  =>  /category/sub-category/my-article-about-food

Setting up a 301 redirect in this case is a good move. It will help consolidate your link signals and focus them on the URL you prefer for ranking.
